# Comparing two columns if One condition is true or a different two is the condition is false in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to determine the formula for this in excel, but I must be doing something wrong. I am not a programmer but here is the logic. This is the formula I have now: `=IF(L30="N",IF(G30>F30,"Overspend","Underspend"),IF(G30>E30,"Overspend","Underspend"))`

```
If K2 = "False"     
    If G2>F2    
      return overspend  
   Else  
      return underspend  
Else  
   If G2>E2  
      return overspend  
   Else  
      return underspend
```

Comment: While the general idea of what you want to accomplish is vaguely there, this question would benefit from sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OR()` and `AND()` are great functions.

```
=IF(OR(AND(K2="N",G2>F2),AND(K2="Y",G2>E2)),"Overspend","Underspend")

=IF(                   -- If
   OR(                 -- either
    AND(K2="N",G2>F2), -- all of this 
    AND(K2="Y",G2>E2)  -- or all of this
   )                   -- is true
   ,"Overspend"        -- show this
   ,"Underspend")      -- otherwise show this
```